# Wix - install as non-admin and add to GAC

Tags: wix, gac, wix3.5, gacutil, non-admin

I am writing an installer using WIX, and I need to add a .dll file to the GAC.
I use:

```
 <File Id="my.dll" Name="my.dll" DiskId="1" Source="..\MyResources\" KeyPath="yes" Assembly=".net" />
```

This works perfectly fine for the Administrator user, however when i run this from a non-administrator user, the installer fails with an error that i don't have privileges.

Is there a way to overcome this?

If i write a custom action, will i be able to use gacutil from a non-administrator user?

Thanks for your help,
Maxim

Answer (score 1):

Installing to the GAC requires administrator privs.  The only way a standard user can do it is to have the package advertised by an admin.   This way the system will trust the package and when the standard user runs the install it will elevate during the execute sequence and use System to publish the assembly to the GAC.

[How to allow users who are not administrators to install MSI packages](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259459)